# Can you "WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY" with a time uuid

Tags: cassandra, uuid, cql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .views (
    uuid timeuuid,
    country text,
    ip inet,
    region text,
    city text,
    lat text,
    long text,
    metro text,
    zip text,
    video_id int,
    date_created timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(video_id, uuid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (uuid DESC);
```

My question is can i use a Time UUID to reliably cluster order by my table. Or do I need to use a time stamp

I originally used the time stamp field to cluster my views. However I want to try to avoid having the extra data and am curious if i can sort by my time uuid instead.

My limited tests have confirmed this so far, but I want to make sure it will always work.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Sorry, too tired, updated my post hopefully its more clear. thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, TimeUUID is reliably order your data and it's universal unique.**

> A TimeUUID (also known as a v1 UUID) should be a combination of the machine's MAC address and a time component. The included MAC address ensures that the value will be unique across machines.

But if you use timestamp and More user concurrently view the same video, then same timestamp can be generate and so you will lose some of the view.

Note : You should generate timeuuid using standard library. Ex. `UUIDs.timeBased()` or cql function `now()`

Comment: so the newest uuid will always be at the top, guaranteed?

Comment: yes, the newest uuid of a video_id will be always top for that id